# auto cinder volume when creating nova instance via REST API

Tags: openstack, cinder, nova

When i use `horizon` to create a nova instance, it is creating volume based on selected flavor and image.
But when i determine flavorRef and ImageRef via rest api [endpoint](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=create-server-detail#create-server), the created instance has no volume!

Have to create a volume and attach it manually?

Answer (score 0):

The default in horizon dashboard is indeed to create a new volume when creating a new instance. The "yes" button is preselected in the "source" tab. If you want to create a volume via CLI you'll need to also provide the `--block-device-mapping` argument, see `openstack help server create` for more details. I haven't tried that via API directly so I'm not sure if this is applicable for creating instances via API.

Comment: yes its's possible, just need to change the type from local (is default) to volume in block_device_mapping_v2